# Insert_batch ou update_batch - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!
Podem me ajudar com um insert_batch ou update_batch.

Através do codigo abaixo eu preciso inserir, atualizar ou deletar um item do banco de dados.

Da forma que está eu estou conseguindo inserir, mas meu problema está quando vou atualizar, pois quando é para atualizar, atualiza somente o ultimo id, enquanto outros dados(id) que tambem sofreram alterações no formulario, não são atualizados no banco de dados.

No objeto contém um campo `crud`.

Se este campo, recebe a letra `C`, então devo inserir um item no banco de dados
Se vier `R`, não faço nada.
Se vier `U`, então atualizo o campo,
Se vier, `D`, então deleto o item do banco de dados.

Veja o objeto
`$endereco = $objeto_decode->enderecos;`

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [cep] => 30810-350
        [logradouro] => Rua Flor da Laranjeira
        [numero] => 71
        [complemento] => 
        [bairro] => Jardim Alvorada
        [cidade] => Belo Horizonte
        [uf] => MG
        [observacao] => Teste
        [crud] => R
        [devedor_id] => 1
        [id_origem_dados] => 1
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 3
        [cep] => 32667-538
        [logradouro] => Rua Jhenifer Naiara Aguiar
        [numero] => 29
        [complemento] => 
        [bairro] => Paulo Camilo
        [cidade] => Betim
        [uf] => MG
        [observacao] => GGG
        [crud] => R
        [devedor_id] => 1
        [id_origem_dados] => 1
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 4
        [cep] => 32667-538
        [logradouro] => Rua Jhenifer Naiara Aguiar
        [numero] => 29
        [complemento] => CS
        [bairro] => Paulo Camilo
        [cidade] => Betim
        [uf] => MG
        [observacao] => 
        [crud] => R
        [devedor_id] => 1
        [id_origem_dados] => 1
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 5
        [cep] => 32667-538
        [logradouro] => Rua Jhenifer Naiara Aguiar
        [numero] => 29
        [complemento] => CS
        [bairro] => Paulo Camilo
        [cidade] => Betim
        [uf] => MG
        [observacao] => AAAATTT
        [crud] => R
        [devedor_id] => 1
        [id_origem_dados] => 1
    )
)
```

Então estou fazendo o seguinte:

```html
$array =  (array) $endereco;
foreach ($endereco as $endereco)
 {
    $endereco_id           = $endereco->id;            
    $endereco_cep          = $endereco->cep;
    $endereco_logradouro   = $endereco->logradouro;
    $endereco_numero       = $endereco->numero;
    $endereco_complemento  = $endereco->complemento;
    $endereco_bairro       = $endereco->bairro;
    $endereco_cidade       = $endereco->cidade;
    $endereco_uf           = $endereco->uf;
    $endereco_observacao   = $endereco->observacao;
    $endereco_crud         = $endereco->crud;
    $endereco_devedor_id   = $endereco->devedor_id;
    $endereco_origem_dados = $endereco->id_origem_dados;
    //echo $endereco->crud);
 }
        
 $batch[] = array(
    'id'              => $endereco_id,
    'cep'             => $endereco_cep,
    'logradouro'      => $endereco_logradouro,
    'numero'          => $endereco_numero,
    'complemento'     => $endereco_complemento,
    'bairro'          => $endereco_bairro,
    'cidade'          => $endereco_cidade,
    'uf'              => $endereco_uf,
    'observacao'      => $endereco_observacao,
    'devedor_id'      => $endereco_devedor_id,
    'id_origem_dados' => $endereco_origem_dados,
    );
    
    if ($endereco_id == 0 && $endereco_crud == "C")
  {
      $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_devedor_endereco', $batch, 'id');
  } 
  elseif ($endereco_id != 0 && $endereco_crud == "R")
  {
      echo ($endereco_id.' retrive'.'<br>');
  } 
  elseif ($endereco_id != 0 && $endereco_crud == "U")
  {
      $this->db->update_batch('tbl_devedor_endereco', $batch, 'id');
  } 
  elseif ($endereco_id != 0 && $endereco_crud == "D")
  {
     echo ($endereco_id.' delete'.'<br>');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso (somente o último item é processado) acontece porque a chave que fecha o `foreach` está no lugar errado ela deveria estar no final. Como você precisa verificar o que fazer com cada registro não faz muito sentido utilizar `insert_batch()`. Elimine essas atribuições que estão sobrando.

```
$array =  (array) $endereco;
foreach ($endereco as $e){
   $batch[] = array(
            'id'              => $e->id,
            'cep'             => $e->cep,
            'logradouro'      => $e->logradouro,
            'numero'          => $e->numero,
            'complemento'     => $e->complemento,
            'bairro'          => $e->bairro,
            'cidade'          => $e->cidade,
            'uf'              => $e->uf,
            'observacao'      => $e->observacao,
            'devedor_id'      => $e->devedor_id,
            'id_origem_dados' => $e->origem_dados,
        );

    if ($e->id == 0 && $e->crud == "C"){
            $this->db->insert_batch('tbl_devedor_endereco', $batch, 'id');
        }elseif ($e->id!= 0 && $e->crud == "R"){
            echo ($e->id.' retrive'.'<br>');
        }elseif ($e->id != 0 && $e->crud == "U"){
            $this->db->update_batch('tbl_devedor_endereco', $batch, 'id');
        }elseif ($e->id != 0 && $e->crud == "D"){
           echo ($e->id.' delete'.'<br>');
        }
}// FIM DO FOREACH
```